# Why Pentaho Schema Workbench dimension can't find columns in my table?

Tags: postgresql, pentaho, database-schema, workbench, mondrian

I created a Cube in schema workbench, with one measure, and 4 dimensions : age, gender, time, geography. Nothing fancy and everything works, except for the age dimension : I can add the table in my hierarchy, but does not find any columns, whereas my columns exist (postgresql db) and rows exist.
I even created foreign key constraint in my postgresql db in my fact table to my age dim, it works, but not in Schema Workbench.

Any ideas why is that so ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you have master table for age? can't able to understand your data model.anyways are you getting any error in pentaho schema workbench? i mean when you do mapping with age table and taking specific column.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Nope, no error. If in postgresql I copy (create table as select *) the age table, and select this one in schema workbench, it works. But I'd like to understand why it doesn't work with one and works with the copy…